# Sitecore 7 SOLR search with Complex Types

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7

I have successfully managed to set up Sitecore with SOLR. Following a few guides I managed to build a POCO class against which I'm mapping data from SOLR searching (via Linq provider).

My question is, does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing a complex query? According to [this article](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/06/Sitecore-7-POCO-Explained.aspx), doing this requires the creation of a Type Converter. I cannot find how a Type Converter of this type would be created however.

The note states that:

> The code below requires that you have built a TypeConvertor for the
>   Article class to tell the DocumentMapper how to store the Article
>   class in the index as well as fetch it as well

The example of a TypeConverter provided in the "Developers Guide to Item Buckets and Search" is merely to cast a GUID to a Sitecore.Item.ID, and has nothing to do with supporting a Complex Type "Article" as indicated in the "Sitecore 7 POCO's explained" article.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how such a TypeConverter can be constructed??

Comment: What do you mean by a 'complex query' ? Are you talking about mapping of complex values back to POCO objects or how to index complex values from custom types into the index or just how to query non-string fields through Linq ?

Comment: Thanks Stephen,

Yes, I'm referring to mapping complex values back to POCO objects, which the article I linked to seems to indicate is something that is possible with a Type Converter? I may have completely misinterpreted that section though.

Comment: You could have a method/non-indexed property on your class that gets the related article by ID.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, that makes sense, but I'm not sure if that is the right way forward? Wouldn't that potentially create a bottleneck?

Isn't the whole point of using SOLR to avoid having to go through the API for large data sets?

Again, Apologies if some of these questions sound absurd, but I'm still finding my way through things and keep stumbling over issues.

Thanks!